# Apply Website Branding/Functionality Based on URL

Tags: java, jsp, properties, themes

I am creating a series of websites that will share a common java code base but will each have a different look and feel, as well as make slightly different calls to a database. Each site will have a unique URL (www.siteA.com, www.siteB.com).

The necessary database information is stored in properties files that appear to be loaded when the applications are deployed (to a JBoss 4.2.3 server). The CSS and images are in static folders.

What I want:

- The user enters www.siteA.com
- The "unbranded" site is initialized
- Java (or whatever needs to) checks the URL to see which files to load
- siteA.properties and siteA.css are loaded from the siteA resources folder
- siteA's customized site is served to the client

If www.siteB.com is entered, all of its info would be loaded. When I want to add a new Site C, I will just create a siteC resources folder, put the SiteC versions of properties and CSS in it, and the underlying common code should take care of noticing that www.siteC.com was entered and grab from the new folder. All of this should happen without having to redeploy any of the elements common to all the sites.

I think I've mostly figured out how to get the CSS/images side of this working, but I can't get the properties files loaded this way.

Is this even possible? I haven't even been able to find a high-level discussion of the process.

Comment: Why don't you just do this processing on the server? Why do this client side at all?

Comment: I want to do it server-side. The first four steps in the list above should all be done on the server before it serves up the final page.

Comment: If it helps at all, language localization is the perfect example of what I'd like to do - but I need to do it for things that aren't languages.

Comment: does `www.siteA.com` and `www.siteB.com` imply that you want to have different behaviors on different servers? Or are you setting up a server with mulitple DNS names. Or mabe you mean context roots `www.site.com/A/` and `www.site.com/B/` the answer will depend on which situation you are trying to solve.

Comment: One server with multiple DNS names. Depending on which DNS name is used to access the site, it should serve up a different "brand" of the site. But I don't want full-blown copies of everything - just of the things that differ.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look up the HOST http header and output the relevant information for each server using a PHP script. You can output common content using file from an HTML file stored somewhere on the server.

Comment: Why don't you just use Apache virtual host and have the correct files under the correct document root? Are you just not using any scripting at all?

Comment: Virtual hosts would work with full-on copies of each site in each document root - that's not what I'm looking for. The server is already configured. I need the java side to load the appropriate properties files based on the url - all sites will use different urls but point to the exact same document root. Then, based on the url, different properties/css/images will load.